# Store and retrieve a multidimensional array using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

I have a multidimensional array in PHP like this:

```
$array = array(
    "Part1" => array(
        "Subpart1" => array(0, 1),
        "Subpart2" => array(1, 0)
    ),
    "Part2" => array(0),
    "Part3" => array(0, 1, 0)
);
```

Now I want to store this array in a MySQL table and retrieve it exactly like this again on another PHP page.

I've been trying using `serialize()` and `unserialize()`

```
$array= serialize($array);
```

and then on the other page

```
$array= $row['Array'];
$array2 = array();
$array2 = unserialize($array);
```

But I seem to do something wrong, in the beginning I got a `var_dump` of *bool(false)* and now I get a `var_dump` of *NULL*.

Comment: Just a small comment, you can simplify your unserialization code from those 3 lines to just one:

$array2 = unserialize($row['Array']);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code looks ok...

One thing that can catch you out is if your column is too small - if you use VARCHAR(255) your data can be truncated and won't unserialize.  If you add the value of `$row['Array']` I could see if it's whole.

Answer (score 4):

Use column type TEXT. Serialized data often doesn't fit VARCHAR(255).

Answer (score 1):

You could use json encode, json_encode($array) and you will get a string value in json notation so you can store in database, and retrive and do a json_decode($string, true) so you cand convert in an array again. If you don't pass the true argument to the json_decode, it will converted to a stdClass.

Answer (score 0):

**Particulars**
      **Quantity**
      **Rate**
      **Amount**
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
        **Amount Sum**    
        
          
             
      
    
    
      
        
        **Others  

            
            
          Others Amount**
             
          
            
        
    
    
      
        
                        **Tax       
        
            Total**

This is my table in php/html.
I need to store and retrieve the php Particulars(p),Quantity(q),Rate(r) as a separate table format